# function call as array element

Tags: c++, function

i have some difficulties understanding and implementing the following issue:

storing a function call in an array, i.e. having an array of doubles and a function that return a double....i would like to when calling e.g. an element of the array, lets say myArray[0], it should call the function myArray, that returns a double.

```
double myFunction(){return mydouble}

double myArray[3];
...
cout<<myArray[2]<<endl; <- should call myFunction and return "mydouble"
```

Comment: Please decide for either C or C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++ look up [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), for C read more about [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).

Function pointers can be used in C++ as well, but are not as flexible as `std::function`.

C++ solution:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    double myStructFunction() { return 2.0; }
};

std::function<double()> myArray[3];

MyStruct myStructure;

myArray[0] = []() { return 1.0; };
myArray[1] = std::bind(&MyStruct::myStructFunction, myStructure);
myArray[2] = myFunction;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << "Calling `myArray[" << i << "]` : " << myArray[i]() << '\n';
```

For the assignment of `myArray[0]` look up [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and for the `myArray[1]` assignment look up [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: I was about to ask about the possibility of using lambda functions with `std::function` myself.  Do you know off hand whether this will work with VC++ or g++, and from which version?  (I know that neither really support C++11, but some things do work in recent versions---I can use _simple_ lambdas in VC++11, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Builds fine with GCC 4.7.1. Also tested with clang version 3.3 (trunk 176337). Not tested yet with VC++.

Comment: @JamesKanze Just checked with VC++2012 Express, works fine there too. Can't say anything about 2010 though.

Answer (score 3):

Then you should have array of function pointer in order to achieve this:

`typedef double(*MyArray)();`

`MyArray MA[3];`

You can store functions with signature `double function_name()` into array,like:

`MA[0] = MyFunction;`

`cout<< MA[0]()<<endl;`

Comment: [That is not a valid declaration](http://ideone.com/sMTSDJ). Functions cannot return plain arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can do it in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Functions */
static double fn_0(void){return 0.;}
static double fn_1(void){return 1.;}
static double fn_2(void){return 2.;}

int main(void)
{
    /* Declaration */
    double (*pfn[])(void) = {fn_0, fn_1, fn_2};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", pfn[i]()); /* Usage */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    double myFunction()
{
    double mydouble = 1;
  return mydouble;
}

int main()
{
  double myArray[3] = {0,0,0};
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    myArray[i] = myFunction();
    cout << myArray[i];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is different in C and in C++, and also different in
C++11 and in pre-C++11.

In all of these, you can have a simple array of pointers to
functions:

```
double (*array[3])() = { &f1, &f2, &f3 };
```

To call a function:

```
std::cout << (*array[i])() << std::endl;
```

This is very limiting, since it means that the functions in
question cannot depend on any other data.  For this reason, it
is usual in C to create a `struct`:

```
struct F
{
    double (*pf)( void* );
    void*    data;
};

F array[3] = { { &f1, NULL }, { &f2, someData }, { &f3, NULL } };

std::cout << (*array[i].pf)( &data ) << std::endl;
```

(There are, however, a lot of cases, particularly in numerical
calculation, where this is overkill.  It's mostly used by
callbacks.)

In C++, you also have the option of defining an abstract base
class, with a virtual function (which will be overridden in each
derived class), and saving pointers to instances of various
derived classes:

```
class F
{
public:
    virtual ~F() {}
    virtual double operator()() const = 0;
};

F const* array[3] = { &obj1, &obj2, &obj3 };

std::cout<< (*array[i])() << std::endl;
```

Finally, in C++11, there is a standard object `std::function`
which encapsulates all of this.  (You'll have to look this up
yourself, however.  Like most people, I don't yet have access to
a compiler which fully supports C++11, so have been unable to
practice this.)

Answer (score 1):

How about something as simple as this?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct O
{
  std::map<size_t,double(*)()> m;
  double operator[](size_t index)
  {
    return m[index]();
  }
};

double mydouble = 1.25;

double myFunction()
{
  return mydouble;
}

int main()
{
  O myArray;
  myArray.m[2] = &myFunction;
  std::cout << myArray[2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/XGpEWn)):

```
1.25
```